# calculate logical and phycal bits

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system

I am reading OS concepts book and saw the practice question : 

`Consider a logical address space of 64 pages of 1024 words each, mapped
onto a physical memory of 32 frames.
a. How many bits are there in the logical address?
b. How many bits are there in the physical address?`

how to calculate?
I have the answer but I need to know a method to solve such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Logical Address(LA) = PageNumber + PageOffset

Similarly, 
Physical Address(PA) = FrameNumber + FrameOffset

for a page to fit perfectly inside a frame its size has to be equal to frame size
hence, frame size = 1024 Words

therefore, PageOffset = FrameOffset = 10 bits

number of pages = 64
so, minimum number of bits required to represent any page out of 64 pages = 6 = PageNumber

similarly, minimum number of bits required to represent any frame out of 32 frames = 5 = FrameNumber

hence using above stated equations :
LA = 6 + 10;
PA = 5 + 10;